# Buttons are not shown in jQueryUI Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

im new to jQueryUI and tested it a bit.

Here is my current code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tools</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="include/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="include/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src='js/javascript.js'></script>

  <style>
   #draggable
   {
    width: 99%; 
    height: 500px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
   }

   #my_new_window
   {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: solid; 
    border-width: px;
   }
  </style>

  <script> 
   $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable().resizable();
   });

   $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({});
   });

   $(function() {
    $("input[type=submit], a, button").button().click(function(event)
    {
     event.preventDefault();
    });

    var give_me_new_window = function () {
     var div = document.createElement('div');
     document.body.appendChild(div);
     div.id = 'my_new_window';
     div.textContent = 'Hello world.';
     div.className = 'ui-widget-content';

     $(function()
     {
      $( "#my_new_window" ).draggable().resizable();
     });
    };
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table border="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <colgroup>
   <col width="20%">
   <col width="60%">
   <col width="10%">
   <col width="10%">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
   <td><img src="media/pictures/Logo.jpg" width="100" height="56" alt="Logo"></td>
   <th align=center><b>Tools</b></th>
   <td align=right>Welcome User  </td>
   <td>  XXXXX YYYYYYY</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  <hr> 
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
   <h3>Bla bla blub</h3>
   <hr>
   <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#tab1">Role Analysis</a></li>
     <li><a href="#tab2">Risk Analysis</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1">
     <table border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
     <colgroup>
      <col width="200">
      <col width="200">
      <col width="200">
      <col width="200">
     </colgroup>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="A submit button"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="A submit button"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="A submit button"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="A submit button">
     </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2"><p>Here comes the Text.</p></div>
    <p>Drag me around</p>
    <input type="button" name="Text 2" value="Text 2 anzeigen"
        onclick="give_me_new_window();"
    >
   </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As you can see I have already implemented dragable and sizable windows and tabs in the windows. Now I want to add some buttons in the windows . My problem is that every time I am pasting the code from jQuery (http://jqueryui.com/button/) the Buttons are still in the standard HTML-Style and the dragable and sizable functions of my windows are gone.

The code which causes this problem is this one. If I don't paste it in the code, everything works fine.

```
$(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
    .button()
    .click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Has anybody an idea to fix this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you have 'button()' ? remove it and give a try

Comment: Removed it and the tabs and my sizable and dragable windows are working again but the style of my buttons is still in standard HTML-Style

Comment: Verify your tables layout. You have a `<tr>` in the middle of `<td>` in the first table, and an unclosed `<td>` in the second table.

Comment: Use browser console to check for errors. Would have already solved some of this if you just looked in console

Comment: @Maverick As the other users mentioned, your code contains some errors in css javascript and html. Preventing unexpected behavior, fix your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed to write **});** in your code

**replace**

```
$(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
    .button()
    .click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    });
```

**with**

```
$(function() {
$( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
.button()
.click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if you close your functions properly: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kgm9o693/29/) Using a http://www.jsfiddle.net is a great way to test small pieces of code.

Also, you are probably copy pasting everything. You don't need `$(function () {})` everytime. It is just saying wait for the document to be loaded fully and then execute all this script. I would suggest you don't use the shorthand at all, but start your code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {//Open

    $( "input[type=submit], a, button" )
    .button()
    .click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    }); 

    //More logic

});//End
```

Another tip: seperate CSS and Javascript with external files from the HTML